# Theoretical Doubt about derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I know that the derivative of $y=\frac{x}{ax^2+b}$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b-ax^2}{(ax^2+b)^2}$, but why can't I get the same answer if I'm going to derivative, something like $(a\cdot y)x^2-x+by=0$ ? If I manipulate the terms can I change them when it's been derivative ? I was thinking it would be more easy, however I didin't get the same answer.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The numerator should be $b - ax^2$ I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating $$ay\cdot x^2-x+by=0$$

$$ay\cdot 2x+a\frac{dy}{dx}x^2-1+b \frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-2axy}{ax^2+b}$$

Replacing the value of $y$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-2ax\cdot\dfrac x{ax^2+b}}{ax^2+b}=\cdots$$

Comment: I'm wondering now "How didn't I see the substitution of y ?" It's make sense at all now. Thank you Lab : )